# Search by has_one_attached on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a model with `has_one_attached` file

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord

has_one_attached :file, dependent: :nullify
```

`file` has a signed_id field, I want to find the document by `file signed_id value`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed`

```rb
attachment = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(signed_id_value).attachments.first
```

If you need `Document` instance

```rb
document = attachment.record
```

**Note**: It doesn't depend on file type association `has_one_attached` or `has_many_attached`. There is only `attachments` association for both.